# How to stay in SoundCloud's rate limit while streaming audio?

Tags: soundcloud, rate-limiting

SoundCloud recently enabled their 15k-a-day rate limit.

My app will serve quite a few visitors a day. The rate limit is expected to be hit very easily.

Can the stream URL be cached? Is there any way to stream and stay in the rate limit when going over because you have too much traffic?

The devs haven't made an application form yet to ask for higher limits..

Comment: same problem here, I'm hitting the rate limit everyday. 15K is obviously too little even for a small amount of active users. Hope that SoundCloud could raise the limit accordingly, I do not mind to purchase for the extra usage if the price is reasonable.

Comment: Hope thare will be some news regarding this.